# How to detect changes to values through a specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given

> ```
> Id | RouteId | Milepoint | RoadCondition 
> -: | :------ | --------: | :------------ 
>  1 | A       |         0 | X             
>  2 | A       |         1 | X             
>  3 | A       |         4 | Y             
>  4 | B       |         0 | Y             
>  5 | B       |         2 | null 
>  6 | B       |         5 | null 
>  7 | B       |         6 | Z             
>  8 | B       |        18 | Z             
>  9 | C       |         0 | X
> ```

I am after

> ```
> Id | RouteId | Milepoint | RoadCondition | ContinuousId
> -: | :------ | --------: | :------------ | -----------:
>  1 | A       |         0 | X             |            1
>  2 | A       |         1 | X             |            1
>  3 | A       |         4 | Y             |            2
>  4 | B       |         0 | Y             |            3
>  5 | B       |         2 | null          |            4
>  6 | B       |         5 | null          |            5
>  7 | B       |         6 | Z             |            6
>  8 | B       |        18 | Z             |            6
>  9 | C       |         0 | X             |            7
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @Example TABLE (
>   Id INT primary key,
>   RouteId varchar(50),
>   Milepoint INT,
>   RoadCondition varchar(50),
>   ContinuousId INT
> )
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf950727b9b1a3e093f19e941470c403)*

I am using SQL Server 2017.

What I am after is the ability to generate the `ContinuousId`, which travels along `RouteId ASC, Milepoint ASC` and when the `RouteId` or `RoadCondition` changes, it increments the `ContinuousId`

I know that I'll want to use `LEAD()` but handling NULLs is the part I am not sure how to approach the problem, because I can't just COALESCE the NULLs because no two nulls can be assumed to be the same value, it should increment whenever it sees a NULL for RoadCondition

Comment: What are you expecting here as output?

Comment: The example is the expected output, the `ContinuousId` is the column I do not know how to generate. Ill update the answer to make that more clear

Comment: The confusion is that you have ContinuousID in your table and in your sql fiddle. I am guessing that column is what you are attempting to derive from the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as clever as DENSE_RANK but I think this works as well

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE (
    Id INT primary key,
    RouteId varchar(50),
    Milepoint INT,
    RoadCondition varchar(50)
)


INSERT INTO @Example
VALUES 
    (1, 'A', 0, 'X')
    ,(2, 'A', 1, 'X')
    ,(3, 'A', 4, 'Y')
    ,(4, 'B', 0, 'Y')
    ,(5, 'B', 2, NULL)
    ,(6, 'B', 5, NULL)
    ,(7, 'B', 6, 'Z')
    ,(8, 'B', 18, 'Z')
    ,(9, 'C', 0, 'X')

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN                    
            RouteId = LAG(RouteId) OVER (PARTITION BY RouteId ORDER BY Milepoint) 
            AND
            RoadCondition = LAG(RoadCondition) OVER (PARTITION BY RouteId ORDER BY Milepoint) 
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS StartOfNextIsland 
    FROM @Example
)

SELECT *, SUM(StartOfNextIsland) OVER (ORDER BY RouteId, Milepoint) AS ContinuousId
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` with `COALESCE()` :

```
select e.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by RouteId, coalesce(RoadCondition, cast(id as varchar(255)))) AS New_ContinuousId
from @Example e;
```

Comment: This gives the correct uniqness but because Milepoint isnt considered with the ordering the numbering is off

Comment: This solution dont give the answer required. row 4,5,6 are wrong.

Comment: if you insert a row RouteId, Milepoint, RoadCondition (A, 5, X) it will result in an incorrect solution saying its apart of the other A,X's  when really its disjointed (an island of its own)

Answer (score 0):

The below is with CTE's

```
;with cte as (
    select *,1 [New_ContinuousId] from @Example e where Id=1
union all
    select e.*
        ,cte.New_ContinuousId+(case when 
                    e.RouteId is null
                    or e.RoadCondition is null
                    or cte.RoadCondition is null
                    or cte.RouteId  is null
                    or e.RouteId<>cte.RouteId  
                    or e.RoadCondition<>cte.RoadCondition  
                    then 1 else 0 end) [ccc] from @Example e
        inner join cte on cte.Id+1=e.Id
)
select * from cte
```

Result:

```
Id  RouteId Milepoint   RoadCondition   ContinuousId    New_ContinuousId
==  ======= =========   =============   ============    =================
1   A       0           X               1               1
2   A       1           X               1               1
3   A       4           Y               2               2
4   B       0           Y               3               3
5   B       2           NULL            4               4
6   B       5           NULL            5               5
7   B       6           Z               6               6
8   B       18          Z               6               6
9   C       0           X               7               7
```

The below is a shorter version with LAG that give the same result as above.

```
;with cte as (
    select * ,case when LAG(RoadCondition+RouteId,1) over (order by Id)=RoadCondition+RouteId then null else 1 end  [cc]
    from @Example e 
)
select Id,RouteId,Milepoint,RoadCondition,ContinuousId,count(cc) over (order by Id) [New_ContinuousId] from cte
```